# differences between $Y^X$ and $C(X,Y)$ in topology

Tags: general-topology

Can someone please explain me what are the definitions and differences between $Y^X$ and $C(X,Y)$ in topological spaces?

Comment: What definition?

Comment: $Y^X$ and $C(X,Y)$ can be equipped with many different types of topologies

Comment: $Y^X$ is the set of all functions $X\to Y$, and $C(X,Y)$ is the set of all _continuous_ functions $X\to Y$.

Comment: If you mean **the compact-open** topology on $C(X,Y)$ and **the topology of compact convergence** on $Y^X$, then $C(X,Y)$ is a subspace of $Y^X$ where $Y$ is a metric space.